# modify a view that other views depend on

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-base

I use LibreOffice Base to create weekly reports. I have one table (named `time_spent`) that contains a lot of normalized data, and I am using views to do the processing required to produce the reports I need.

Every week I add new data to that table, and I want to export fresh reports for only that week.

Instead of re-creating all the views that are being used to create my report *every* week, I was hoping to create a view named `time_spent_selection`, which is essentially `SELECT * FROM "time_spent" WHERE "week" = '2015-04'`, and use that to assemble all subsequent views. Every week would then only have to change that `WHERE` clause and automatically get the reports for the right week.

However, LibreOffice base denies saving any changes made to `time_spent_selection` view with the following error message:

> Table is referenced by view: bugs in statement [DROP VIEW "time_spent_selection"]

[image: error message dialog]
[image]

Here, `bugs` is one of the views that references `time_spent_selection` in it's definition.

## Question:

**How can I force-modify this view, on which other views depend?**

I understand that - if this were possible - all views would have to be recomputed, and this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a limitation of the backend database, which by default is HyperSQL Database (HSQLDB) version 1.8 - if you are using the default backend, the documentation is at http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/1.8/guide/ch09.html and does not have anything like ALTER VIEW or REPLACE VIEW.  You have to use DROP VIEW, which is only allowed if there are no dependencies.

You have the option to upgrade to the current version of HSQLDB (version 2.3), which supports the ALTER VIEW statement (http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#dbc_view_creation). The GUI would probably still not support the transaction, but you could use the Tools->SQL window to directly issue the ALTER VIEW command to the database.  Instructions on how to upgrade the database component to version 2.3 is in this forum thread: [[Tutorial] Splitting an "embedded HSQL database"](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=83&t=65980)

Alternately, instead of hard-coding a particular date into the view's SQL, have the view reference a filter/dummy table for the date.  Then you can just open up the one-column, one-row "reportDate" table and alter the date in there each week without touching the view.